# Kafka streams attempts to connect to localhost despite StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG pointing to a different host

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I have a kafka streams configuration as below.  I've confirmed in a debugger that `KafkaProperties` does indeed have a single entry for bootstrap servers with the value `myhost.mydomain.org:9092`.

When I run my app, I get the warning:

```
WARN 83530 --- [-StreamThread-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : 
[Consumer clientId=...-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=mygid] 
Connection to node 1001 (kafka/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I've confirmed the broker is up and running and accepting connections.   I don't know where it is getting localhost from.

```java
    @Bean("myKSConfig")
    public StreamsBuilderFactoryBean kafkaStreams(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties,
                                     @Value("${spring.application.name}") String appName) {
        var props = new HashMap<String, Object>(kafkaProperties.getProperties());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaProperties.getBootstrapServers());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, appName);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerde.class);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, "state_data_dir");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 10 * 1000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, JsonNode.class);
        var config = new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(props);
        return new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(config);
    }
```

With these properties

```
...
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=myhost.mydomain.org:9092
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't edit `/etc/hosts` to create this mapping from that address to `127.0.0.1`, then the bootstrap is returning its `advertised.listeners` configuration

Check that configuration in the brokers to verify your client can connect with the advertised address

Comment: Just to clarify; the property is called bootstrap because that is just an initial connection made  to one of the brokers; after that initial connection, the cluster returns the actual addresses the client needs to connect to (via its configured properties).